Is just saying "excuse me" weird to native speakers?
Here's the sentence:

He approached the guard, "Excuse me, could you help me with something?"

Is this usage odd? Does it flow naturally?
How unnatural is it to not use something like Sir/Ma'am/miss etc. after excuse me, before starting the question?
Also, would this work instead, "Excuse me but could you help me with something?"

Perfectly natural in British English; we would consider it very formal to address someone as Sir/Madam.

Perfectly natural in American English. In certain circumstances, you might use Sir/Madam (Ma'am) but rarely. One place they used Ma'am was to the former Queen of England, RIP.

It may or may not fit within the worldview or priorities of you or those you're addressing, but some recent perspectives on gender hold that the only way of knowing someone's gender for sure is for them to tell you, not to guess by appearance, and since most honorifics like "sir" or "ma'am" are gendered, this could be a reason to skip them, or replace them with something else like "Excuse me friend...." Regardless of worldview, if there's any uncertainty, guessing wrong is never good!
